# Android Studio cannot resolve org.junit

Tags: android, android-studio, junit

I am using JUnit tests in Android Studio 1.2.2. The tests run without a problem. The only thing that puzzles me is that Android Studio cannot resolve the actual org.junit package. Obviously it does resolve it otherwise the tests wouldn't run. But the import and annotations are marked red in Android Studio as shown here. Is this a bug in Android Studio? I tried rebuilding the app and restarting Android Studio but this doesn't correct the problem.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*; // cannot resolve symbol 'junit'

public class CanadaTest
{
    @Test
    public void testCountryName() throws Exception
    {
        int x = 0;
        x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` files.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`.

Comment: and in build-variants your Test Artifact is "Unit Tests" ?

Comment: Yes. As mentioned, everything is configured properly and the tests run. If something wasn't configured properly, the tests wouldn't run and AS would complain.

Comment: try "invalidate caches and restart"

Comment: Shortest answer ever.

Answer (score 20):

Put this in your gradle file:

```
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: You should put that in `testCompile` for unit testing. Use `androidTestCompile` instrumentation tests.

Comment: yup just thought of giving it a try

Comment: @JaredBurrows that should be an answer. Solved my error. Thank you.

Comment: testCompile  is now obsolete, for newer projects this might help: "Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation' and 'testApi'."

Comment: Use `testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'` as `testCompile` is obsolete

Answer (score 15):

**If none of the above work**, it might be that your test classes are in the wrong directory.

I ran into this issue because my text classes were in the `/main/java` dir instead of the `/test` dir where they're supposed to be...

**In short:**

Make sure your test classes are in the `/test` directory!

Comment: Thank you, really saved my day as I mistakenly put it in the unit test directory.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem and it turned out that it was just due to my having left my build variant set to "release".  Once I changed it back to "debug", Android Studio did a build and when it finished the red errors on junit annotations went away.
[pic of build variant setting in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ8Rl.png)

Comment: That did it for me too, and it kinda makes sense. Anyone with more experience with builds care to explain why.

Comment: sorry i am just now replying to your request for an explanation. the reason is related to the way gradle handles scopes. it has a larger scope that includes testing and it has a smaller scope that excludes testing and just builds the app for deployment. when you select debug in android studio it is using the larger scope that includes testing. when you pick the release in android studio it is using the smaller gradle scope that excludes testing. if you have the release option selected it seems to get confused about what to do with the junit stuff since it is not defined within that scope.

Comment: @user3064141 You've saved my day!! I had a kotlin-only module as a library module for the project. I've setup junit5 dependencies for the library module but the dependencies weren't resolved when syncing the gradle configuration. It turns out that I selected the build variant of the project as "release" in "Build variant" section. I've been scratching my head for 2 days over this haha

Answer (score 2):

I resoleved it by combination of some answers and some changes:

1.Make sure to set prepare `targetSdkVersion` , `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion`.

2.I used the last `Android Gradle Plugin Version` and `Gradle Version`.

3.Add some lines to buil.gradle on app level(I mark them with '\*' ):

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zima.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"   //*
        apply plugin: 'maven'   //*
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'  //*
        implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'   //*
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'  //*
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'  //*
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'  //*
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])   //*
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')   //*
    }
}
```

4.build.gradle on project level is like this:

```
    buildscript {
     repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        apply plugin: 'java'  //*
         }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem** 
Classes and annotations of the *org.junit.** were not found in the instrumentation tests (androidTest). These classes wer found in the junit tests (test).

**Solution**:
Switching the *Build Variant* from **Release** to **Debug**.

Comment: Thanks bro, I owe you one!

Answer (score 1):

May be in your gradle file you have something like this:

```
configurations {
    debugImplementation.exclude group: "junit", module: "junit"
}
```

After removing everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you've reinstalled android studio remember by default it is not using your systems JDK (Project structure -> SDK location -> jdk location).

Answer (score 0):

change `junit` to the latest version

`testImplementation 'junit:junit:'`

to

`testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'`